# Curvature and position of tangent space

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let $M$ be a hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^d$, $x_0 \in M$ and $T$ the tangent space of $M$ at $x_0$. Which of the following are true ?

1. If the sectional curvature of $M$ at $x_0$ is strictly positive then $M$ is locally of the same side of $T$ near $x_0$.
2. If the sectional curvature of $M$ at $x_0$ is strictly negative then $M$ is not locally of the same side of $T$ near $x_0$.

I know this statement is true if $M$ is a surface of $\mathbb{R}^3$ but I don't know for other manifolds.

Comment: By Gauss Curvature you mean sectional curvature? I feel for higher dimensional manifolds the term Gauss curvature is not usually used...

Comment: Yes I mean sectional curvature. I edit.

Comment: IIRC, the question isn't meaningful unless $M$ is a _hypersurface_, a submanifold of codimension one: Otherwise the tangent space doesn't separate the ambient space, and "same side" has no more meaning than speaking of "the same side of the tangent line" of a space curve.

Comment: Do you mean to say that $M$ is a _**Riemannian submanifold**_ of $\mathbb R^d$? A [sub-Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-Riemannian_manifold) is a different thing entirely.

Comment: And as a follow-up to Andrew's comment, you probably want to talk about the Gauss-Kronecker curvature instead of the sectional curvature in the hypersurface case. Then expressing $M$ locally as a graph and doing a Taylor expansion should do the trick.